# css3 media queries responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am currently using css3 media queries for building a layout.  I have all the media queries working, but there is a small "quirk" in the design.  I will provide the code below:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #LeftNav, #RightNav {display:block;}
    #MidCol {background:#ff0000;}
}

@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    #LeftNav, #RightNav {display:block;}
    #Midcol {background:#ff0000;}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    #MidCol {background:#00ff00;}
}
```

My question has to do with these media queries.  I'm using very simple styles to transition from one layout to another.  First, the red background is displayed correctly.  Once I start to resize the screen I am expected to go from red to green, but this isn't what I'm getting.  I am getting red, then no color at all, and then green.

Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong with my media queries?

Comment: Be kind and rewind.... wait, wrong domain... oh yeah, up vote, down vote, comment on or edit your question, select an answer, or close your question

Answer (score 1):

Typo:

```
#Midcol {background:#ff0000;}
```

You need `#MidCol`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  I guess all I needed as an extra pair of eyes :P

Answer (score 0):

If your code is *exactly* as posted, it's because you typoed `#Midcol` in the 980-1199 media query.